Tips for adding a little colour back to a patch on a wooden table!
I left a bowl with a white shirt soaking in Vanish fabric powder on my mum’s old wooden table and it frothed over and spilled, and now it’s taken a patch of the dark brown out of the wood. I don’t want to revarnish the table, and it’s old and marked anyway, but the patch is like a big pale orange blob, is there anythjng I could use on it to help even it out more? Doesn't have to be perfect, but lessen the obviousness. Thanks so much!!
PS. Please be kind, am new here. :)

You could try getting some stain from the local hardware store. It is quite possible that the new stain won't match the color exactly, but it may be less noticeable since the table is already splotchy.
If you can tell what kind of wood the table is made of, or take a good picture to your hardware store's paint technician, they might give you some guidance to what color of stain to try.
